# Python cgi, save query result

Tags: python, forms, cgi

Suppose, there is a web page with a form to query a huge database. Every time I look up some data, I must enter the field values, submit the form, and wait for the returned list. I want to automate this process, because I look for a single data set, and want to see when it appears in the database. For this purpose I wrote a Python cgi script that pulls the page, fills the form with GET parameters and submits it. All fine, the results appear. Next, I want to save the returned values in a file. With a cron job I can monitor this file to see when it changes. 
However, my script does not save the returned list, it saves the filled form.

I tried:

```
lynx -dump
curl
wget -E -H -k -p
```

All of them save the filled form, instead of waiting for the returned values. It takes several seconds to run the query, but I don't think it is the problem. I am sure I miss something fundamental here, like setting the html headers and this is why Python's urllib2 thinks the page is loaded. But I don't have experience with those.